# How can I let my framework create instances of user defined subclasses

Tags: java, design-patterns

My framework will create objects which have interface A.

The user is responsible for defining concrete subclasses B, C, D...

What is the correct way for me to tell the framework here are my concrete classes which you can create yourself (as many as you wish).

My initial thoughts were something like the command design pattern. The difference is that it would be a generic class (B, C, D...) and it would **return** A. Would this be appropriate? Another approach would be to do something similar with a factory method.

Is there an alternative pattern to solve this problem?

The user should be able to create as many alternative subclasses as they wish without modification to the framework. The framework should only know about interface A.

Answer (score 1):

You're saying that the framework will `create` instances of classes of which it knows nothing?

The standard sort of way to do this would be to use a factory or provider.

```
interface A { ... }

class B implements A { ... }
class C implements A { ... }

Supplier<B> factoryB = () => {
    return new B();
};
Supplier<C> factoryC = () => {
    return new C();
};
```

Then the framework can use instances of `Supplier<? extends A>`

```
Supplier<? extends A> factory = ...;
A a = factory.get();
```

A concrete implementation of this pattern is [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html), which allows third parties to provide implementations of an interface at runtime. There is an [Oracle tutorial on ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html)

Answer (score 0):

The nature of your problem statement is to deal with object creation mechanism. You want to let framework create the instance of user defined classes. So, this problem statement falls under the Creational Pattern. You can design your application by using Factory Pattern. Later you can move to Abstract Factory Pattern in case of more complicated classes or family of classes increases.